# How I can get specific values from URL in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

How I can get specific values from the following URL I need to get only 3 values

```
http://earnprofitclickint.com/UserWorking/Successfull.aspx?lr_paidto=U9925362&lr_amnt=2.00&lr_currency=LRUSD&lr_store=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.earnprofitclickint.com&lr_merchant_ref=&lr_paidby=U3563444&lr_fee_amnt=0.00&lr_transfer=143636187&lr_timestamp=2013-12-05+18%3A31%3A33&ctl00%24contentplaceholder1%24amount=&ctl00%24contentplaceholder1%24id=70&ctl00%24contentplaceholder1%24txtamount=+2&ctl00%24contentplaceholder1%24username=networker&lr_encrypted=04E20ADA982A2AF9C1C64DB3C1601BA596373E22D7B4D21813A51C43DC0198CD&lr_encrypted2=59C8269D431F915360F3B8179EC95181D8C458AB91D72AF3DFC1DC0DFDAC4F64
```

I want to get 3 values from the above URL return from Liberty Reserve Website and want to insert these three values to database using LINQ TO SQL

I need to get the following values

```
r_amnt=2.00 ID=70 username=networker
```

---

I have written the code in page load to get the above values when the response come and Redirect to my successful page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        ID.Value = Request.QueryString["id"].ToString();
        UserName.Value = Request.QueryString["username"].ToString();
        Amount.Value = Request.QueryString["lr_amnt"].ToString();

        SaveLocalHistory();
        Divmessage.Visible = true;
    }
}

public void SaveLocalHistory()
{
    MLMDataContext db = new MLMDataContext();

    UsersInvestement pd = new UsersInvestement();
    pd.Amount = Convert.ToDouble(Amount.Value);
    pd.UserId = Convert.ToInt32(ID.Value);
    pd.UserName = UserName.Value;
    pd.Description = "This amount has been received From LR";
    pd.IncomeTypeId = 4;
    pd.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
    db.UsersInvestements.InsertOnSubmit(pd);
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

---

This is a manual change in the URL:

http://earnprofitclickint.com/UserWorking/Successfull.aspx?lr_paidto=U9925362&lr_amnt=2.00&lr_currency=LRUSD&lr_store=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.earnprofitclickint.com&lr_merchant_ref=&lr_paidby=U3563444&lr_fee_amnt=0.00&lr_transfer=143636187&lr_timestamp=2013-12-05+18%3A31%3A33&ctl00%24contentplaceholder1&amount=&ctl00%24contentplaceholder1&id=70&ctl00%24contentplaceholder1%24txtamount=+2&ctl00%24contentplaceholder1&username=networker&lr_encrypted=04E20ADA982A2AF9C1C64DB3C1601BA596373E22D7B4D21813A51C43DC0198CD&lr_encrypted2=59C8269D431F915360F3B8179EC95181D8C458AB91D72AF3DFC1DC0DFDAC4F64

---

If I change it manually then it works. Any idea?

Comment: Any help will be appriciated thanks

Comment: Thanks for your help: i have done according to the above but it just get one querysting Amount.Value = Request.QueryString["lr_amnt"].ToString(); value not the other it gives error i think due to empty spaces before username and id the URL CAN anyone help me out thanks alot

Comment: i have updated the code like ID.Value = Request.QueryString["id"].ToString(); UserName.Value = Request.QueryString["username"].ToString(); Amount.Value = Request.QueryString["r_amnt"].ToString();

Comment: when i changed the url manually then it works and remove the %24

Comment: http://earnprofitclickint.com/UserWorking/Successfull.aspx?lr_paidto=U9925362&lr_amnt=2.00&lr_currency=LRUSD&lr_store=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.earnprofitclickint.com&lr_merchant_ref=&lr_paidby=U3563444&lr_fee_amnt=0.00&lr_transfer=143636187&lr_timestamp=2013-12-05+18%3A31%3A33&ctl00%24contentplaceholder1&amount=&ctl00%24contentplaceholder1&id=70&ctl00%24contentplaceholder1%24txtamount=+2&ctl00%24contentplaceholder1&username=networker&lr_encrypted=04E20ADA982A2AF9C1C64DB3C1601BA596373E22D7B4D21813A51C43DC0198CD&lr_encrypted2=59C8269D431F915360F3B8179EC95181D8C458AB91D72AF3DFC1DC0DFDAC4F64

Comment: So is it working now?

Answer (score 1):

Your parameter names are not `username` and `id`, they are `ctl00$contentplaceholder1$username` for `username` and `ctl00$contentplaceholder1$id` for `id`

Since `%24` when URLDecode gives `$` , you need to do the corresponding replacements too.

Try this:

```
ID.Value = Request.QueryString["ctl00$contentplaceholder1$id"].ToString();
UserName.Value = Request.QueryString["ctl00$contentplaceholder1$username"].ToString();
Amount.Value = Request.QueryString["r_amnt"].ToString();
```

and it should work. Let me know otherwise! :)

Comment: Let me know if it does not, there is one more thing that might be a problem. I'll get it sorted in-case this does not work.

Comment: Thanks sunny Rgupta for the help: when i use as you mentioned above it again gives nullable exception so i copies this %24 to notepad and view and came to know that this was $ sign so i have updated it like    ID.Value = Request.QueryString["ctl00$contentplaceholder1$id"].ToString();
            UserName.Value = Request.QueryString["ctl00$contentplaceholder1$username"].ToString();
            Amount.Value = Request.QueryString["lr_amnt"].ToString(); and it works thanks for your best idea.

Comment: That is exactly what I had in mind when I said there could be another problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly certain that the query string values are case sensitive, meaning that this code

```
ID.Value = Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString();
UserName.Value = Request.QueryString["UserName"].ToString();
Amount.Value = Request.QueryString["lr_amnt"].ToString();
```

should probably be in this form

```
ID.Value = Request.QueryString["id"].ToString();
UserName.Value = Request.QueryString["username"].ToString();
Amount.Value = Request.QueryString["r_amnt"].ToString();
```

if you wanted to pull out "r_amnt=2.00 id=70 username=networker"

---

As an aside, note that you never dispose of your database context. This can be dangerous in that it is possible your connection will not close for a very long time, I would suggest doing this instead:

```
using( MLMDataContext db = new MLMDataContext() )
{
 UsersInvestement pd = new UsersInvestement();
 pd.Amount = Convert.ToDouble(Amount.Value);
 pd.UserId = Convert.ToInt32(ID.Value);
 pd.UserName = UserName.Value;
 pd.Description = "This amount has been received From LR";
 pd.IncomeTypeId = 4;
 pd.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
 db.UsersInvestements.InsertOnSubmit(pd);
 db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

The using statement ensures that `Dispose` is called on the DataContext (which inherits from IDisposable) and will properly close the connection once the actions complete.

Comment: Thanks for your help: i have done according to the above but it just get one querysting  Amount.Value = Request.QueryString["lr_amnt"].ToString();  value not the other it gives error i think due to empty spaces  before username and id the URL  CAN anyone help me out thanks alot

Comment: i have updated the code like ID.Value = Request.QueryString["id"].ToString();
UserName.Value = Request.QueryString["username"].ToString();
Amount.Value = Request.QueryString["r_amnt"].ToString();